# Выбрать из структур максимальную по какому-либо полю

Tags: c#, linq

Допустим есть набор простых структур:

```
struct Cat {
    string name;
    int age;
};
```

Как лучше выбрать самую молодую кошку? У меня получилось только так:

```
 Cat cat = cats.Select(c => c).OrderBy(c => c.age).First();
```

Как по мне, то этот код делает лишнюю работу, так как выбирает не только самую молодую кошку, но еще и сортирует все остальные тоже, что не требуется. Если использовать `Min()`:

```
var cat = cats.Min(c => c.age);
```

то в `cat` будет только возраст, а не вся кошка целиком. Можно ли получить всю кошку, используя `Min()`?

---

код:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    struct Cat
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        Cat[] cats = new Cat[] 
        {
            new Cat() {name = "Мурка", age = 2},
            new Cat() {name = "Васька", age = 1},
            new Cat() {name = "Рыжик", age = 5}
        };

        Cat cat = cats.Select(c => c).OrderBy(c => c.age).First();
        Console.WriteLine(cat.name);
    }
}
```

или [тут](http://ideone.com/dSiEkR)

Comment: Cat cat = cats.First(c=>c.age==cats.Min(x=>x.age));

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev Неплохо)